# Arduino GPS/GSM receiver (Uno+A7 Elecrow)

Tags: string, text, arduino, gps, gsm

I'm trying to make a GPS/GSM receiver with an Arduino Uno. My program is trying to ana]yse the incoming strings with a few `if`s. Then I want to convert them to save them on an SD card, or send them as SMS.

This is the correct information from the GPS:

```
+GPSRD:
$GPGGA,151420.000,5222.61362,N,01658.51086,E,1,03,8.9,0.0,M,,M,,0000*44
$GPRMC,151420.000,A,5222.61362,N,01658.51086,E,0.46,160.58,201017,,,A*67
$GPVTG,160.58,T,,M,0.46,N,0.86,K,A*3B
```

The line I need is the third one, because there are coordinates. I want to save them. So I made some functions. I'm trying also to navigate the whole device by SMS commands. Everything is in the code. Here is the code:

```cpp
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <SD.h>
#include <string.h>

#define rxPin 7
#define txPin 8

String message="lalala", callingnumber="";
String response="";
String coords;
String data[13]={"","","","","","","","","","","","",""};
String thetime=(""), date=(""), latitude=(""), longitude=("");
SoftwareSerial mySerial(rxPin, txPin);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  mySerial.begin(19200);
  while (!Serial) {
  }
  digitalWrite(3, HIGH);
  delay(2000);
  digitalWrite(3, LOW);
  for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    mySerial.println("AT");
    Serial.println("AT");
    delay(1000);
  }
  mySerial.println("");
  delay(1000);
  mySerial.println("Jestem gotowy!");
  delay(1000);
  mySerial.println("s - lokalizacja / g - wlacz gps / o - wylacz gps");
  delay(1000);
  Serial.println("AT+GPS=1");
  delay(1000);
  Serial.println("AT+CMGF=1");
  delay(1000);
  while (Serial.available()) {
    mySerial.write(Serial.read());
  }
}

void loop() {
  RecData();
}

void RecData() {
  int firstindex, lastindex;
  Serial.setTimeout(1000);
  response = Serial.readString();
  firstindex = response.indexOf("$GPRMC");
  lastindex = response.indexOf("$GPVTG");
  if (response.indexOf("+CMT: ") > 0) {
    int numberindex = response.indexOf("+48");
    if (response.indexOf("Start") > 0) {
      callingnumber = response.substring(numberindex, numberindex+12);
      SendSMS("wlaczono");
      OpenGPS();
    }
  }
  if (response.indexOf("+CMT: ") > 0) {
    int numberindex = response.indexOf("+48");
    if (response.indexOf("Stop") > 0) {
      callingnumber = response.substring(numberindex, numberindex+12);
      SendSMS("zatrzymano");
      CloseGPS();
    }
  }
  if (response.indexOf("+CMT: ") > 0) {
    int numberindex = response.indexOf("+48");
    if (response.indexOf("Sms") > 0) {
      callingnumber = response.substring(numberindex, numberindex+12);
      SendSMS(message);
    }
  }
  int a = 0;
  for (int i=firstindex; i<lastindex; i++) {
    mySerial.print(response[i]);
    if(response[i] == ',') {
      a++;
    } else {
      data[a] += response[i];
    }
  }
  mySerial.print(firstindex);
  mySerial.print("::");
  mySerial.print(lastindex);
  mySerial.println(" loop is working");
  date = data[9];
  thetime = data[1];
  latitude = data[3] + data[4];
  longitude = data[5] + data[6];
  message = date.substring(0,2) + "." + date.substring(2,4) + "." + date.substring(4,6) + " " + thetime.substring(0,2) + ":" + thetime.substring(2,4) + ":" + thetime.substring(4,6) + " coords: " + latitude.substring(0,2) + "'" + latitude.substring(2,4) + "''" + latitude.substring(5,10) + "'''" + latitude.substring(10,11)+ " " + longitude.substring(1,3) + "'" + longitude.substring(3,5) + "''" + longitude.substring(6,11) + "'''" + longitude.substring(11,12);
  for(int ii = 0; ii < 13; ii++) {
    mySerial.print(data[ii]);
    data[ii] = "";
    //czyszczenie na szybko
  }
  if (firstindex < 0 && lastindex < 0) {
    mySerial.write("test");
    mySerial.print(response);
    mySerial.print(response.length());
  }
}

void OpenGPS() {
  mySerial.println("wlaczam gps");
  delay(500);
  Serial.println("AT+GPSRD=1");
  delay(500);
  mySerial.println("Wlaczono");
}

void CloseGPS() {
  mySerial.println("Wylaczam GPS");
  delay(500);
  Serial.println("AT+GPSRD=0");
}

void SignalQuality() {
  mySerial.print("Jakosc sygnalu: ");
  delay(1000);
  Serial.println("AT+CSQ");
}

void SendSMS(String msg) {
  mySerial.println("wysylam...");
  delay(500);
  Serial.println("AT+CMGS="+callingnumber);
  delay(500);
  Serial.print(msg);
  delay(500);
  Serial.println((char)26);
  delay(500);
  mySerial.println("wyslano");
}
```

I'm looking for some help, because it doesn't work well. Here is the screenshot of the executed program:

[image]

The response is not good. There was some text conversion to get 13 strings of message.

Please help, if I missed any information I can edit the post.

Thanks.

Comment: try removing the `Serial.setTimeout(1000);` in the second line of `void RecData(){` and adding this `delay(1);` after `response = Serial.readString();`.

Comment: modulator, did it work?

Comment: i tried with Serial.setTimeout(1000); or delay(1); and without both. Still the same problem

Comment: What you call `trash from the GPS` isn't. It's an invalid fix. You should NOT expect the GPS to provide you any time, every time, an exact, valid fix. You should also never expect the NMEA messages to come in the order you saw once. Or expect only the NMEA messages you want. You should code expecting things to break.

Comment: Much simplier code, without any conversion of strings returns every second line $GPRMC. So it can return my data corectly. I mean receiver. There is problem with storing data in response variable.